Как работает многопоточность?
Что есть что в схеме ядро->процесс->поток ? Получается, что на одном ядре может быть один процесс при этом говорится, что разницы между процессом и потоком особой нет, и в то же время на одном процессе может быть несколько потоков. То есть получается, что смысл существования этих взаимозаменяемых понятий заключается только лишь в переносе конкурентного выполнения программы на два разных уровня - 1) на уровень потоков, где у каждого потока(ну то есть задачи/программы) есть доступ к общим ресурсам, и 2) на уровне процессов, где  у каждого потока(иначе говоря, задачи или программы) такого доступа нет. Действительно ли нет никакой разницы в общем случае между выполнением одной программы в нескольких процессах и выполнением программы в одном процессе с несколькими потоками, кроме той, что переключения контекста(конкурентность) в первом случае происходит на уровне процессов, а во втором случае на уровне потоков в одной области памяти?

Если потоки не обмениваются данными, то никакой разницы нет. Если потокам надо общаться, разница может быть огромная.

Если говорить об уровне железа, то никакой разницы нет. Отличие в том, что для разных потоков одного процесса в MMU (memory management unit) разных ядер (на которых в данный момент исполняется код потоков) будет загружена одна и та же карта виртуальной памяти (она задает преобразование виртуальных адресов памяти (именно ими оперирует процессор) в физические), а для разных процессов ОС загружает разные карты.

Вообще говоря программа - это и есть процесс.

Подскажите, а может ли выполняться несколько потоков созданных в рамках одно процесса По-настоящему одновременно? Или когда мы говорим о потоках внутри процесса они всегда работают посредством переключения контекста? То есть настоящее параллельное выполнение программы возможно только на нескольких ядрах?

Ядро - это сущность аппаратного обеспечения, а процессы и потоки - сущности операционной системы или ее пользовательского API. Тут нужен ликбез. Почитатйте "Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера", Харрис; либо на худой конец "Архитектура компьютера", Танненбаум.

@user7860670
Спасибо за материалы

Процесс это просто бокс для потоков - исполняют код именно потоки. В свою очередь ядро процессора имеет конвейер "Pipeline", куда поступает программный поток кода. В одном ядре могут быть 2 конвейера, тогда ядро называют с "Гипертрейдингом" НТ. Если процессор 2-ядерный с НТ, то получаем 2 ядра и 4 потока. Соответственно если у вас процесс 4-поточный, то на таком ЦП НТ(2:4) все 4 потока будут исполняться параллельно во времени, причём без переключения контекста планировщиком (при условии, что других процессов для исполнения нет).
